# Is it tool recommendation if the task obviously needs a library to finish, but the question doesn't contain any words to recommend libraries?

Tags: discussion, scope

I found this question closed as tool recommendation:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466804/convert-flat-text-file-to-pdf

While I agree the task mentioned almost surely requires external library to finish, the question body seems doesn't contain any words about library suggestion. Is it appropriate to close this question as tool recommation?

Or a generalized example of this case, if I have a question:

What library can I use to do X?

And I change to:

How can I do X?

Would the question become on-topic?

Comment: A "How do I do very broad thing X" question would likely be closed as too broad.

Comment: see also: [What's the difference between “How can I do X?” and “What library does X?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256226/839601)